# Replace number in double quotes with string empty

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string like this

```
<span id="1">1 </span>ABC<br><span id="2">2 </span>DEF<br><span id="3">3 </span>GHI<br>
```

now I want to remove the id="1", id="2", id="3"

I used

```
MyString.Replace("id=", string.Empty).Replace("\"[0-9]+\"", string.Empty);
```

But I failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
String s="<span id=\"1\">1 </span>ABC<br><span id=\"2\">2...";
Regex re=new Regex("id=\"[0-9]+\"");
s=re.Replace(s, "");
```

should do.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can help you here. You can do the following

> `(new Regex(@"id=\"[0-9]\"")).Replace(str, string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the hole replace with a single regular expression?

```
Regex re = Regex("id=\"[0-9]+\"");
MyString = re.Replace(MyString, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove what's in double quotes, then

```
Regex rx = Regex("id=\"[0-9]+\"");
string result = rx.Replace(MyString, @"id=""")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you need to remove, `id="1", id="2", id="3"` the simple Regex pattern will help you,

```
        string InputString = "<span id=\"1\">1 </span>ABC<br><span id=\"2\">2 </span>DEF<br><span id=\"13\">3 </span>GHI<br>";

        Regex myRegexPattern = new Regex("id=\"[0-9]+\"");
        string outputResult = myRegexPattern.Replace(InputString, "");
```

The output that I got from it was,
`<span >1 </span>ABC<br><span >2 </span>DEF<br><span >3 </span>GHI<br>`